# Open CV with CDT error?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I have configure an Openc CV include file path in Tool Setting, but it still gives warning in my code.
warning is :

```
          Unresolved inclusion: <highgui.h>
```

my code is :

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
 Mat image;
 image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
 if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
  {
    printf( "No image data \n" );
    return -1;
   }
   namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( "Display Image", image );
   waitKey(0);
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different include if you work with `cv::Mat`:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```